# Possibility of determining a certain length in a triangle.

Tags: geometry

The figure is on the bottom of the question.

Suppose I have a triangle $ABC$ with an additional point $M$ on the middle of $AB$. Suppose that I know the following three quantitites, where $\ell(\cdot)$ represents the lenth of the line.

- $y:=\ell(AM)$
- $k:=\ell(AC) - \ell(CM)$
- $l:=\ell(BC) - \ell(CM)$

Is it possible to determine $x:=\ell(CM)$? And if so, is this value unique?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to find length of $x$ terms of $ y,k,l ?$ , the median?

Comment: Yes, In terms of $y,k,l$. Those are the only three quantities I know beforehand. The actual triangle is unknown, but drawn here for explaining purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd and 3rd values determine two hyperbolas (with foci respectively $M,A$ and $M,B$).
The point C is the intersection of these two hyperbolas.
So yes, it's possible.

We first draw $A,B,M$, this we can obviously do. Then we draw the two hyperbolas, we see where they intersect, and that determines $C$ (I do not say it's a unique $C$, maybe there are more than $1$ or maybe $0$ solutions for $C$, I didn't investigate that).

See also:  [Hyperbola](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperbola.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I am also interested in the uniqueness of the length $x$. Does anyone have any ideas concerning this?

Comment: Well, you have to write the two equations of the two hyperbolas, and see where they possibly have common points (x,y) and how many these common points are (depending on the values you know). Try to google "intersection of two hyperbolas".